# C# MVC4 from razor to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

In a MVC4 view, I'm displaying a list of items with radio buttons as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Select this address" onclick="setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("SelectCustomerAddress", new {addressId = item.Id})')" />
```

Further down the view I have a checkbox where the user must accept the terms of service, as follows:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TermsAccepted)
```

I would like to change the 'onclick' so that the ToS are accepted before the user proceeds. Do I need to use javascript, and if yes, how?

Then how should the error be displayed? Using ValidationSummary?

Edit:

Using javascript below, the onclick changed to:

```
<input type="button" value="Select this address" onclick="selectAddress(@item.Id)" />
```

and the javascript to the following:

```
           <script>
                $(function () {


                    function selectAddress(selectedId) {
                        if ($('#TermsAccepted').is(':checked')) {
                            setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("SelectCustomerAddress", new { addressId = selectedId})')
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#checkErrorMsg').toggle();
                        }  
                    }
                })
            </script>
```

Comment: No, i need to see where you're getting `item` from, is it within a `foreach (var item in Model.Items)` if so `item` should be fine, or is it just in the document, in which case it needs to be `Model.Id`

Comment: it is within a foreach

Comment: then make sure your `controller` is getting all the information for the `model`, i use `viewmodel`s to do this. Put a breakpoint in somewhere to check all the `model`s have IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use chrome Inspect element, you can view the ID of the `CheckBoxFor(model => model.TermsAccepted)`, then you could just check it in the function `setLocation` before you navigate the user away.

This would be done in javascript. I use Jquery. So on the razor page I do this:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       // any javascript in here
   })
</script>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TermsAccepted)
```

This will automatically load the javascript ready for use when the document loads. Then just simple test using something like this:

```
if($('#TermsAccepted_Id').is(':checked'))
```

`#TermsAccepted_Id` is your checkbox, and as the code shows, you're just seeing if it has been checked. If it hasn't, simply display an error. You could display an error like this:

```
<script>
       $(function () {
           // any javascript in here
           var setLocationFunction = setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("SelectCustomerAddress", new {addressId = item.Id})');

           function checkTsAndCs() {
              if($('#TermsAccepted_Id').is(':checked'))
              {
                 //Everything okay, proceed
                 setLocationFunction(); // this is where you want to call the function from above, it'd be better to make it a variable for use later, i'm not 100% sure on how to call a function, that would be a quick look up for you ;)
              }
               else
              {
                 $('#checkErrorMsg').toggle();
              }  
           }
       })
</script>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TermsAccepted)
<div id="checkErrorMsg" style="display:none">Please accept these before you go on.</div>
```

In your view put this:

```
<input type="button" value="Select this address" onclick="checkTsAndCs()" />
```

I'm not sure whether you have to put `javascript:` in front of `checkTsAndCs` in the onclick function, but again, you can find that out ;), i usually write all my jquery javascript in the spur of the moment, and then instantly forget everything afterwards, funny I know, but my brain thinks it doesn't need to remember it.

Comment: That's a start. But because I cannot change the setLocation function, how are the calls to checkTsAndCs in onclick and the call to setLocation in checkTsAndCs (also passing a parameter to it)?

Comment: As an additional note, please be aware that changing the property name will result in a different ID and without tests, you will not be able to catch the issue where your event will never be fired in your client.

@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsAccepted, new { id = "TermsAccepted_id })

Comment: I'll edit it for you, and yes @PieterGermishuys you're absolutely correct. Do watch out for that Ivan-MarkDebono

Comment: The only problem left is that item.id in setLocationFunction results in a syntax error because it is not known.

Comment: please put all of your razor view code up, it will depend how you are accessing ur model in the view